# Placement of variable declaration with respect to while loops

Tags: java, loops, variables, while-loop

This program prompts the user for an integer. If the user does not enter an integer, it prompts again until they do. Once an integer is entered, it prints "CS115" five times.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String CS115 = "Hello CS115";
    Scanner scan = new Scanner ( System.in );

    System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");

    int correctInput = scan.nextInt();

    while(!scan.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("Try again > "); 
            scan.next();
    }


    for (int i = 1; i <= correctInput; i++)  {
            System.out.println(CS115);
        }

}
```

On a whim I put the correctInput declaration after the while loop and before the for loop and it worked (see below). But I'm not understanding why what I have above won't work. If I enter 3 for example, nothing happens. If I enter 3 again, I get the desired result.

I suspect that when I enter 3, correctInput is assigned to 3, and the while loop is ignored. I understand this part I believe. But why won't the for loop execute with this correctInput value? The program just terminates, until I enter the value a second time. Upon the second entry, the for loop runs. What's going on here?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String CS115 = "Hello CS115"
        Scanner scan = new Scanner ( System.in );

        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");

        while(!scan.hasNextInt()) {
                System.out.println("Try again > "); 
                scan.next();
        }

        int correctInput = scan.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i <= correctInput; i++)  {
                System.out.println(CS115);
        }           
}
```

Comment: Please show both versions of the code.

Comment: Sorry about that. Done!

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to call `hasNextInt` first to check if the user typed an integer, *then* call `nextInt` to read that integer. If you call `nextInt` before `hasNextInt`, `nextInt` will read an integer, but then `hasNextInt` will expect you to type *another* integer.
This is because, in `Scanner`, `hasNext` is used to check the input *before* you read it with `next`.